# How to share a folder with fullaccess right to a specific user powershell Smbshare

Tags: windows, powershell, share, smb

> how to share a folder with smbshare which receives the user in
> parameter with a $,in my code the name of the folder is the same as
> the user.I can share a folder with full access to a specific name like "Administrator" but not a username like $username.

```
new-SmbShare -Name "$username" -Path "U:\LeProgramme" -ChangeAccess "$username" -FullAccess "$username"
```

Answer (score 0):

The quotes between each variable are not needed, `$username` should be in the format `"DOMAIN\user"` for a Domain Joined computer or `"$env:ComputerName\user"` for a non Domain Joined computer. If the share already exists you can use `Set-ACL` to give permissions to a new user.